# Docker image using Jib plugin: Cant hit rest endpoint locally when container running?

Tags: java, spring, docker, docker-container, jib

I have a very simple `spring boot` web app that I created using spring initializer.

I have added the following `controller`:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("hello")
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping(value = "", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> sayHello() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello!");
    }

}
```

When I run it locally in `intelij` I can hit the following endpoint successfully and get a response:

```
http://localhost:8080/hello
```

I have pushed the image created using `jib` to my `docker hub` registry and can pull the image successfully.

However when I run the `container` via `docker` as follows I get `This site can’t be reached` at the same URL.

```
docker run --name localJibExample123 -d -p 8080:80 bc2cbf3b85d1
```

I am able to run other containers ok and can hit the endpoints, what can be the issue here?

Running docker ps returns this for my running container:

```
"java -cp /app/resou…"   8 minutes ago    Up 8 minutes                  0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   localJibExample222
```

So it seems that my app should be accessible on:

```
http://localhost:8080/hello
```

Comment: are you sure the ports (`docker run ... -p 8080:80 ...`) are the right way around (`localhost`,port `8080` forwarded to container, port `80`)? I would expect it to be `docker run ... -p 8080:8080 ...`.

Comment: is that not correct? I have the same in for a different container and it works as expected?

Comment: I recommend reading [the relevant documentation of `docker run` (`docs.docker.com`)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose).

Comment: When I run this  docker command: docker run --name myNginx2 -d -p 8090:80 nginx > I am able to hit the nginx endpoint at http://localhost:8090/ and get a response? So I thought it should be the same with my java app? Perhaps I am wrong

Comment: Again: I recommend reading the documentation I linked. `nginx` runs on port `80` by default. Spring-boot runs on port `8080` by default.

Comment: thanks I will check it out. I have been able to get it working now using: docker run --name localJibExample22210 -d -p 127.0.0.1:80:8080/tcp myContainer. Is this the best practice?

Comment: I would advice to not map to `localhost`, port `80`. There might be something already running on this port. In general, I recommend to keep mappings simple, so `... -p 8080:8080 ...` would be my go-to.

Comment: thanks. Feel free to add an answer so I can accept it. So by default always map to port 8080 in the container if running a spring boot app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring-boot, by default, runs on port `8080`. The port mapping we are using in the `docker run ...` command maps the host's port `8080` to the container's port `80` (`... -p 8080:80 ...`, [relevant `docker run` documentatn (`docs.docker.com`)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose)). Since there is nothing running on the container's port `80`, we get no response when accessing `http://localhost:8080`.

The fix is straight-forward: we replace `docker run ... -p 8080:80 ...` with `docker run ... -p 8080:8080 ...`. This will map to the container's port `8080`, where the spring-boot application is listening. When we access `http://localhost:8080` now, we will get a response.